# Breach of fiduciary duty for poor management of endowment?

Tags: united-states, education, currency, trusts-and-estates

If the board of trustees of a private university keeps investing the endowment through an expensive firm run by their friends, despite substandard performance, could a case be made for breach of fiduciary duty? The economists employed by the university have long urged the board to invest in index funds instead.

I know I would need to consult a lawyer specializing in this area, but I'd like to know first if I would be laughed at or if this is a reasonable question.

Comment: Are any written ethical or fiscal guidelines the endowment is required to follow when investing?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: In that case, and that it is a private U, they may be able to do anything they want within the bounds of state and federal laws.

Answer (score 3):

> could a case be made for breach of fiduciary duty?

Yes, I think, although not every person or stakeholder would have *standing* to sue the board of trustees of the private university.

The prima facie elements of breach of fiduciary duty are "*(i) the existence of a fiduciary duty; (ii) a knowing breach of that duty; and (iii) damages resulting therefrom*", [*Johnson v. Nextel Communications*, 660 F.3d 131, 138 (2011)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infco20110926088) (I am not aware of any material differences in other jurisdictions).

Absent any explicit disclaimers of fiduciary duty, (1) the element of *existence* of that duty is applicable because the trustees' relation with the university is not one of *arms length*; (2) in their deliberate --rather than negligent-- decision to do business with their friends, the trustees are knowingly and intentionally disregarding the advice from economists of the university, despite the evidenced financial detriment of that deliberate decision; and (3) the element of *damages* would be proved from the expenses as billed by the firm, coupled with any losses the friends' subpar performance may be causing to the university.